# Typescript async method declaration

Tags: typescript, asynchronous, es6-promise

What is the difference between :

```
public myFunction = async (
    req: Request, 
    res: Response
): Promise<Response> => {
    return await myOtherFunction() 
}
```

and

```
public async myFunction (
    req: Request, 
    res: Response
): Promise<Response> {
   return await myOtherFunction()
}
```

I mostly use the first exemple, but when converting a function that is not `async`, my code editor (vs code) uses the second exemple.

Probably not relevant but I am using typescript 3.1.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First one is an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) and second one is called [normal function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions).

Main difference is that arrow functions `this` refers to an parent object/class and normal functions `this` refers to an function itself. If you would use `arrow function` in node and use it on top level it would refer to `undefined`.

[reference code](https://codesandbox.io/s/r0j9kn41lp), heres little reference code which is made in React.js, just to demonstrate the use case.

Comment: According to your links, the first one is a normal function and the second one is an arrow function no ?

Comment: My bad I miss spelled it. It is actually other way around, I fix it to the answer. Good notice!

Comment: Thank you very much, I didn't quite get the difference (not using the `this` keyword a lot) but your answer totally explains what I was wondering about

Comment: Just to make things more clear I also added example of `top level` arrow function to `codesandbox` example.

Comment: Some frameworks like `React.js` uses `this`-keyword a lot so you'll get use to them if you get into one of these frameworks. Otherwise it doesn't affect too much which of these functions you are using.

Comment: Yes that's what I thought. For the moment, I am only programming an API using node/express, so that might explain why I didn't have any issue using either arrow or normal functions